# WPF progressbar not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I set a WPF `ProgressBar`'s Is indeterminate to True and Visibility to Hidden. In a event handler I am trying to make the ProgressBar visible while a `ObservableCollection` is being updated (and a ListView whose ItemsSource is the `ObservableCollection`). I hope `DoEvents(`) from `System.Windows.Forms.Application` can make it visible but it does not. 
I notice `SetPBarHelper(() => { ..} )`  usually finish much earlier than the ListView shows visual changes.

How do I make the `ProgressBar` Visible inside event handler codes ?

How to tell if my `ListView` is still being updated even though the `ObserableCollection` has finished adding items ?

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="GeneralProgressBar" Width="300" Height="15" IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="Hidden"/>

private void SetPBar(bool isVisible)
{
    if (isVisible)
        GeneralProgressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    else
        GeneralProgressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
}

private void SetPBarHelper(Action handler)
{
    SetPBar(true);                // try to make ProgressBar visible
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    handler();                    // use the event handling, which run database query
    SetPBar(false);               // try to make ProgressBar disappear
}


private void CommandForumImagesBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SetPBarHelper(() =>
    {
        if (e.Parameter == null)
            return;
        var vm = e.Parameter as ForumViewModel;
        if (vm != null)
        {

        }
    });
}

public sealed class ImageGroupCollection : ObservableCollection<ImageGroup>
{
    public ImageGroupCollection() : base() { }

    public void Update(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        ClearItems();
        var list = MyDatabase.GetRecords(start, end);
        if (list != null)
        {
            foreach (var g in list)
            {
                Add(g);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()? Isn't that a WinForm thing?

Comment: Have you looked at `BackgroundWorker`? If you put the handler() in a BackgroundWorker it should let you see the progress bar while the query is running.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simply because you are blocking the UI thread. You can't do that.

By the time the UI thread is running the message loop again you have set `ProgressBar.Visible = false`. The `ProgressBar` is never drawn.

Assuming you are using .net 4.5 You need to rewrite the code as follows.

```
private async Task SetPBarHelper(Action handler)
{
    SetPBar(true);                // try to make ProgressBar visible
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    await Task.Run(handler);                    // use the event handling, which run database query
    SetPBar(false);               // try to make ProgressBar disappear
}
```

But overall you need to return control of the UI thread back to the application loop as soon as possible to allow it to redraw the windows, and run the update on a WorkerThread.

Comment: That should be `await Task.Run(handler);`